# How do I move my created object on Python?

Tags: python, string, functional-programming, pygame, shapes

I have created an octagon using Python:

```
bif="hello.jpg" 

import pygame, sys 
from pygame.locals import * 

points=[(-60,20),(-60,-20),(-20,60),(20... 
colour=(0,191,255) 

pygame.init() 

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1000,10... 
background=pygame.image.load(bif).conve... 


x,y=0,0 
movex,movey=0,0 


while True: 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit() 
        if event.type==KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key==K_LEFT: 
                movex=-1 
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT: 
                movex=+1 
            elif event.key==K_UP: 
                movey=-1 
            elif event.key==K_DOWN: 
                movey=+1 
        if event.type==KEYUP: 
            if event.key==K_LEFT: 
                movex=0 
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT: 
                movex=0 
            elif event.key==K_UP: 
                movey=0 
            elif event.key==K_DOWN: 
                movey=0 

        x+=movex 
        y+=movey 

    screen.blit(background,(0,0)) 

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen,colour,points... 

    pygame.display.update()
```

I am a new user of Python. I created an octagon using Python but it won't move!

- How do I move it?
- What coding would I need?
- How would I move this octagon that I created?
- Was there anything I did wrong? What did I do wrong?
- How can I improve this?

Comment: Your code has a lot of ellipses where important data might be. Can you fill those in?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `functional-programming`?

Comment: What are ellipses? Sorry I'm a new user and I don't really know much.

Comment: It really shouldn't be tagged there. It said that I needed at least 5 tags and I didn't know what else to tag it with.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the points for the octagon, but it doesn't look like they are actually changed at all by the `movex` and `movey` variables.

As a short example, if you had a set of points for a square such as this:

```
mysquare = [[10, 10], [20, 10], [20, 20], [10, 20]] #I believe you can use lists and tuples, but in case NOT, switch the nested lists for tuples
```

…you would need to summarily change the `x` values per your `movex` variable. As an example...

```
for point in mysquare:
    point[0] += movex
    point[1] += movey
```

If you're using tuples, you'll have to replace the whole thing as opposed to incrementing the value at a given index.

```
for pt in mysquare:
    pt = (pt[0] + movex, pt[1] + movey)
```

-- EDIT --

So for example, let's look at where this would go in your `while` loop.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex=-1 
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex=+1 
            elif event.key==K_UP: 
            movey=-1  
            elif event.key==K_DOWN: 
            movey=+1 
        if event.type==KEYUP: 
            if event.key==K_LEFT: 
            movex=0  
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT: 
            movex=0  
            elif event.key==K_UP: 
            movey=0  
            elif event.key==K_DOWN: 
            movey=0 

    ##at this point, once you know HOW to move the octagon,
    ##now you need to APPLY the changes to the octagon
    for pt in your_octagon: ##or whatever you end up calling it
        pt = (pt[0] + movex, pt[1] + movey)

screen.blit(background,(0,0)) 
pygame.draw.polygon(screen,colour,points... 
pygame.display.update()
```

I believe this will give you the desired effect, though I've not tested it. But the idea is sound: figure out how you're going to move those points, and then move them.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this. If you were me, what would you put? And can you copy my coding and then put your coding in it? Please and thank you.